# C# Random algorithm until fulfills condition

Tags: c#, algorithm, random

I have the following scenario:

1. Generate `n` numbers of random number from a certain range
2. Sum all the numbers
3. Check if the `sum == x` (x is a number set by user)
4. if `sum != x` then keep running the loop
5. If `sum == x`, then display the list of random numbers that sum up to `x`

Based on this logic, I was able to do so but it takes forever to achieve the result, is there any better / way to solve this problem?

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("starting...");
        List<int> checkList = generate(5);
        while(!checkSum(checkList, 100))
        {
            checkList = generate(5)
        }
        Console.WriteLine("done!");
    }


    private static bool checkSum(List<int> n, int sum)
    {
        if(n.Sum() == sum)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }


    public static List<int> generate(int n)
    {
        Random rng = new Random();
        List<int> list = new List<int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            //int ran = some random number
            list.Add(ran);
        }

        return list;
    }
```

**EDIT**

My scenario here is to obtain `n` combinations of random integer that sums up to 100. The number of combinations is taken from input by user. So the program will give the `n` number of possible combinations that sums up to 100.

Possible combinations:

- 25+37+9+20+9 = 100
- 46+21+13+8+12 = 100

Comment: Your scenario is an algorithm (solution), not a problem.  This algorithm is of course slow because of the brute-force approach.  What is the *problem* that you are trying to solve with a better algorithm?

Comment: `it takes forever to achieve the result` Well obviously.  There is one scenario (all items = 20) that will make your condition true.  Actually the 20 is exclusive, so I don't know how this finishes.

Comment: Print out the sequences that aren't working (not just the successful one) and you'll see where the bug in your code is.

Comment: You can make it a lot faster by changing `rng.Next(5,20)` to something like `rng.Next(20,21)`.

Comment: Are you kidding?   You are not even using int n you send to generate.   You expect 5 rng.Next(5, 20); to total 100.   The max (20) is not inclusive.  Even if 20 was inclusive that would only total if random was the max for  every value.

Comment: You might want to read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Sorry guys for the confusion, I made an edit to the post...my scenario here is to obtain 5 combinations of integer that sums up to 100

Comment: The responses to this question sadden me.  It seems pretty clear that the OP had working code, found it was slow, asked a reasonable question about it, and happened to put in a poor choice of data.  Everyone fixated on the data, rather than the question.  The **question** is to come up with a better algorithm that does the same thing.

Comment: @btilly The OP *doesn't* have working code.  They have code with major problems that result in it not working.  They *didn't* ask a reasonable question about it; they just dumped the code and said "fix it", while not even properly explaining the problem they were trying to solve or the problems that they were having with their implementation.  Your assertion of what the question is *conflicts with the actual question being asked*.  You appear to be basing your response on what you wish the question would have asked, not what it did ask.

Comment: @Servy I am basing it on what the OP's most likely question was.  Note that the original version of the code that I saw would produce the right answers if the hard-coded constants were correct, but sloowly.  The question asked was to find a faster method to solve the given problem.  The constants were wrong.  The code has been through several rounds of questionable edits once people began complaining.

Comment: @btilly So you know the question isn't good, but you think that they could have possibly asked a good question, if they asked something different than they did.  So you *do* realize that it's not a good question.  Note that questions are evaluated based on how good the question is, not how good the question you wish the OP had asked instead is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If  you have a fixed sum and a fixed number of elements you want, look at the problem as partitioning.  For example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace PartitionAndAllocateTEst
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var rand = new Random();
            int desiredTotal = 100;
            int partitions = 5;

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                List<int> result = GetRandomCollection(rand, desiredTotal, partitions);
                Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", result.Select(r => r.ToString()).ToArray()));
            }
        }

        private static List<int> GetRandomCollection(Random rand, int desiredTotal, int partitions)
        {
            // calculate the weights
            var weights = new List<double>();
            for (int i = 0; i < partitions; i++)
            {
                weights.Add(rand.NextDouble());
            }
            var totalWeight = weights.Sum();

            // allocate the integer total by weight
            // http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/340393/allocating-an-integer-sum-proportionally-to-a-set-of-reals/340394#340394
            var result = new List<int>();
            double allocatedWeight = 0;
            int allocatedCount = 0;
            foreach (var weight in weights)
            {
                var newAllocatedWeight = allocatedWeight + weight;
                var newAllocatedCount = (int)(desiredTotal * (newAllocatedWeight / totalWeight));
                var thisAllocatedCount = newAllocatedCount - allocatedCount;
                allocatedCount = newAllocatedCount;
                allocatedWeight = newAllocatedWeight;

                result.Add(thisAllocatedCount);
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Example output:

```
30, 6, 19, 15, 30
36, 8, 22, 10, 24
2, 25, 32, 21, 20
22, 7, 30, 12, 29
36, 21, 22, 0, 21
24, 24, 2, 29, 21
18, 13, 10, 39, 20
11, 19, 20, 27, 23
24, 19, 7, 25, 25
24, 14, 27, 18, 17
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a genetic algorithm.  Start with a population of, say, 100 sets of five random integers.  Sum each set.  Select 50 of the better sets, the ones with a sum closer to 100.  Keep the better 50, dump the other 50 and replace them with tweaked versions of the best 50.  The tweak is replacing one integer in the set with another random integer.

Whenever a member of the population sums to exactly 100, pull it out into your output array and make up the population with a newly generated set of five integers.

Genetic algorithms work a lot faster than brute force.

Answer (score -1):

I don't see why you're being downvoted.  Your problem is clear, and you already knew you had a bad algorithm.

I would solve this in two passes.  Pass 1 is figuring out how many ways there are to get from each partial point you could be to a final answer.  Pass 2 is picking a random path.

For pass 1 you build up an array of arrays.  By number of numbers left to pick, by what you need them to sum to, how many ways are there to get that answer?  (Search for dynamic programming for more on how to do this.)

In pass 2 you go forward.  You know at each step how many ways there are to complete your task, and how many there are for each value you can pick.  You therefore know the probability of picking each value.  So pick a random value in `(0, 1)`, walk through the answers, pick your next number, and proceed.

This general strategy is not just for numbers.  It can be used to generate a random sample of anything that you can count using dynamic programming techniques.