# I need random algorithm that fulfills condition

Tags: c#, algorithm, random

Let's say I have a `Product` table in the database that have the following properties of `id` and `price`:

```
Product
=======
ProductId int PRIMARY KEY
Price int
```

For simplicity reasons, I will put `Price` as `int` datatype. So right now I would like to use a random algorithm that will retrieve `n` number of records from the database whereby the `Price` will sum up to a fixed amount `m`.

For example:

- n = 5
- m = 100

So I will retrieve 5 `Product` records that the `Price` will add up to `100`.

**One Possible Result:**

```
ProductId       Price
=====================
       5          10
     109          27
    2081          31
     139          21
     331          11
======================
           Sum:  100
```

I've tried Brute-force approach but it seems to take ages to get the correct sum of `100`. Is there any algorithm to do this?

Comment: You need to first come up with all possible permutations that add to 100 and then randomly select from there.

Comment: Do you hava a test database for this? Would like to use it as a challenge for myself.

Comment: Saw this yesterday perhaps this answer can be of use http://stackoverflow.com/a/42563928/491907

Answer (score 2):

Your problem can be seen as the `Subset sum problem`. You can find here all the information related with it:

[Wiki:Subset Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem)

If you need exact values the problem is NP (not resoluble with big amounts of data), if an approximation is ok you have some options.